# What does "halt das Schicksal auf" mean?

Tags: meaning, idiom

What does it mean:

> Halt das Schicksal auf, gib mir was einst war mein.

Comment: Yes, it's from [a fairy tale](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6pU2HDO7pw).

Comment: Ok, after watching this I guess "give me what once was mine" refers to youth ("give me my youth back"), and then also "stop fate" makes sense (getting old being fate).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be from a poem or the like, probably from a fairy tale. It is hard to understand if you don't know the context. It's easy to translate, though: "Halt das Schicksal auf" translates literally to "stop fate". "Gib mir was einst war mein" means "Give me what I once owned". It's difficult to relate these two half sentences without knowing what is referred to with "what I once owned" or what kind of fate is to be expected.

After watching [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6pU2HDO7pw) (provided by the author of the question in a comment) I'm rather sure that "give me what once was mine" refers to youth ("give me my youth back"), and then also "stop fate" makes sense (getting old being fate).

Answer (score 1):

Oh, this is the [healing incantation](http://www.lastfm.de/music/Mandy+Moore/_/Healing+Incantation) from the new [Disney's story "Tangled"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapunzel_%28film%29), largerly based upon the [brothers Grimm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothers_Grimm)'s fairy tale "[Rapunzel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapunzel)".

The original incantation is:

> Flower, gleam and glow,
> Let your power shine,
> Make the clock reverse
>
> Bring back what once was mine
>
> Heal what has been hurt,
> Change the Fates' design,
> Save what has been lost
>
> Bring back what once was mine
> What once was mine.

The German translation of this song is:

> Blume leuchtend schön,
> kannst so mächtig sein.
> Dreh die Zeit zurück,
> gib mir was einst war mein.
>
> Blume leuchtend schön,
> lass mich nicht allein.
> Halt das Schicksal auf,
> gib mir was einst war mein;
> was einst war mein.

So, the `halt das Schicksal auf` ("delay the Destiny", "slow down the Fate", "stop the Destiny") is the poetic translation of `change the Fates' design`.

The idea behind is that the healing incantation kept the old witch young, so to say stopping the inevitable process of aging ("the Destiny").

P.S.: After having written the answer I have noticed that the author of the question already provided the link to the original, so my suggestion was correct.